# How to sort by file's modified date on IIS web server in Windows 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Apache has this built in since 1996 which is 17 years ago... for Microsoft's IIS Web server which is available on Windows 7, is there a way to make it be able to sort the file listing by file modification dates?

For example, show the file listing with the label "Date", "Filename", and clicking it will sort the files by that attribute.

The only info I could find is:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732762(v=ws.10).aspx

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /showFlags:Time|Size|Extension|Date|LongDate|None
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/section:directoryBrowse /showFlags:
```

just defines which fields to display, not in what order. AFAIK there is no way to do this in IIS.

I'm using IIS since 1996 and I never had a need for such a feature. Directory Browsing should be disabled on production servers and locally you have other ways to get a good file listing.